# Starting a default program in OSX programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, osx-lion

How do I start XCode (or any other default program associated with a file) and make it open a specific file programmatically?  Similar to double-clicking a .c in Finder - it opens an XCode editor with the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method called `openFile:` on `NSWorkspace` that does exactly this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html

(For bonus points, if you want to do it from the shell, you can use the `open` command.)

Answer (score 0):

Running `open your-file.ext` from a shell or a shell script will cause the Finder to open the file in the default associated app, as if you had double-clicked it.

```
man 1 open
```

for more info on how open works.